# Ubuntu 20.04 server unreachable from external world

Tags: linux-networking, subnet, ubuntu-20.04

i have an Ubuntu server where i can not access the server from external machines.
I have tried to ssh to the Ubuntu machine but it seams that all requests are drooped or does not arrive. I have not set any special routing or ip configuration.

The subnet looks like this:

```
        router
           |
  ---------+--------------------
  |        |         |         |
Ubuntu  raspberry  raspberry raspberry
```

Firstly i enter in the network via a vpn, and after that i want to log in to my Ubuntu machine but i can not do that, so i tried to access the raspberries and when i saw that i can enter to the raspberries i tried to ssh to my Ubuntu server from the raspberries, and it worked.

From the router i see all of the machines.

Anybody can help me access my Ubuntu server without accessing fist one of the raspberries?

## sudo iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [60337:4082282]
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:300]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4920:342818]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4920:342818]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:POST_public_post - [0:0]
:POST_public_pre - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eno1 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_pre
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A POST_public -j POST_public_post
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eno1 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78641:5937844]
:INPUT ACCEPT [78611:5935350]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [46644:3913664]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [46670:3916660]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eno1 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78642:5937896]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [46646:3914420]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eno1 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [19038:1906726]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [47400:3969196]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30649:2765745]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_public - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_post - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_pre - [0:0]
:FWDO_public - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_post - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_pre - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_public - [0:0]
:IN_public_allow - [0:0]
:IN_public_deny - [0:0]
:IN_public_log - [0:0]
:IN_public_post - [0:0]
:IN_public_pre - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eno1 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eno1 -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_pre
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_post
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_pre
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_post
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eno1 -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_pre
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -j IN_public_post
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 11 07:58:24 2020
```

[image of the ssh call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZVrG.png)

Comment: Can you post the output of the `ssh` command you are trying to use to connect, preferably adding the `-v` option?

Comment: @Bert i have attached the image, the ip, port and username has been cut out, but everything else is on the image.
Btw the router sees the ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the problem, with modifying the /etc/netplan/01-network-all.yaml file to the folloving:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - local ip/24
      gateway4: gateway ip
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
```

after that i have runned the following commands:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
reboot
```